# Observer onChanged just called once - LiveData + Flowable (LiveDataStreams)

Tags: android, rx-java, android-livedata, flowable

I am trying to observe the data inside a specific table by getting the elements using a `Flowable<List<T>>`, converting it to `LiveData` by using the library `LiveDataStreams` and then observing this last one. **The observation must start on button click**. First time I user clicks the button, it downloads data from server, saves it into the correspondent table and then sets up the observer. The problem becomes **when I click again on the button**, because it downloads the data and save it into the table, but **it does not call the `onChanged`** method from the `Observer`.

In the code you see that ParentFragment's `onViewCreated` method calls `showItemsList` in there because the other children fragments have to do it like this, but just for this current case I have to start observing the list after the buttons' onclick.

ParentFragment:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mNavController = Navigation.findNavController(getDataBindingObject().getRoot());

    showItemsList();
}

protected void showItemsList() {
    mViewModel.getList().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), listObserver);
}

protected final Observer<List<T>> listObserver = new Observer<List<T>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<T> list) {
        getAct().getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(mViewModel.getTitleId(), list.size()));
        mViewModel.setListAdapter(list);
    }
};
```

ChildFragment (current case):

```
@Override
protected void showItemsList() {
    mDataBinding.searchButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        mViewModel.download()
                .subscribe(downloaded -> super.showItemsList()
                        , t -> DialogUtils.showMessage(R.string.error_binding_data));
    });
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public LiveData<List<T>> getList() {
    if (list == null) {
        LiveData<List<T>> lD = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(mRepository.getList());
        list = new MediatorLiveData<>();
        list.addSource(lD, l -> {
            list.setValue(l);
            list.remove(lD);
        });
    }
    return list;
}
```

Repository:

```
public Flowable<List<T>> getList() {
    if (list == null) list = dao.getItems();
    return list;
}
```

Dao:

```
public abstract Flowable<List<MyItem>> getItems();
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in the code responsible for conversion from `Flowable` to `LiveData`.

Upon first call of `getList()`, you create a `LiveData` object which observes `Flowable`, but after retrieving first item, you stop observing the `Flowable`. Later you assign this `LiveData` to a field.

On second call of `getList()`, you get `LiveData` object assigned to the field (which has no sources), and thus the observer in your fragment is not notified.

You can modify your code like this

```
public LiveData<List<T>> getList() {
    if (list == null) {
        LiveData<List<T>> lD = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(mRepository.getList());
        list = new MediatorLiveData<>();
        list.addSource(lD, l -> {
            list.setValue(l);
        });
    }
    return list;
}
```